# Throttling inbound AMQP messages

Tags: design-patterns, integration, spring-integration, messaging, spring-amqp

My system looks like this:

```
[Q1] --> Service1 --> [Q2] --> ...(processing)... --> ServiceN --> [Outbound queue]
```

The queues are RabbitMQ 3.5.6. I'm using Spring Integration 4.2.1, Spring AMQP 1.5.1 and Spring Integration Java DSL 1.1.0.

I would like to throttle the consumption of messages from the queue `Q1` by the `Service1` depending on how many messages are currently in processing and haven't reached the `Outbound queue` - eg. I want to have max. 10 messages being processed at a time. That is because the processing part consumes a lot of resources and I don't want to overload the system.

My current configuration of the initial part of the flow is simply as follows:

```
IntegrationFlows
    .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "Q1"))
    .handle(message -> service1.process(message.getPayload())
    .get();
```

`Service1` and `ServiceN` can communicate (it's the same JVM), so I am able to implement a locking mechanism between them so that `service1.process()` blocks before proceeding with the execution if the "in processing" message limit is reached. That is what - if I understand correctly - @Gary Russell suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497307/how-to-throttle-message-subscription-for-a-spring-amqp-ascyn-consumer#comment30639984_20498514). It will however result in the messages being picked up from the broker and hanging there for a while in an unacked state. Is there a way to just not pick up the messages from the queue at all?

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20498514/466738) of @Artem Bilan to use `SimpleMessageListenerContainer.stop()/.start()` seems quite heavyweight looking at the implementation and all the shutdown/startup logic that would be invoked.

Also both answers are two years old now. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using the message-driven adapter, no. The broker will push messages to the consumer (according to the `prefetch-count`).

I am not sure why you object to the message sitting in an un-ack'd state.

An alternative is to use a simple polled `<int:inbound-channel-adapter/>`, with say 10 threads in the poller, and in the POJO the adapter invokes, use a `RabbitTemplate` to `receive()` messages, but this is less efficient than a message-driven adapter.

Comment: Thanks, Gary - it wasn't a really strong objection against picking up the messages and then waiting with processing them. I thought it would be just cleaner (design-wise) to not consume them if I know I'm unable to process them at the moment. But in the end having a throttle right at the beginning of the flow is fine, too.